# How do I list out all the articles per category in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I have a website powered by the MediaWiki CMS. I would like to create a page that lists out all the categories on the site with links to respective articles under those categories.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [CategoryTree](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCategoryTree) extension and its parser tag.